# LibGDX - Perspective camera using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I haven't found any example which uses perspective camera in LibGDX(OpenGL ES 2.0). How to initiate it and use it in render method? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To some extent you can use a perspective camera as the ortho camera (to set position, look at, up vector). The one big difference is that the viewport size (what you see on screen) is determined by the distance to the object and the field of view angle. There is plenty of theory around the web, but to get started in libgdx you can follow this [example](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectionViewportCamera)

**EDIT:**
   Example provided uses GL 1.x I thought you just didn't know how to use a perspective camera. You mixed up two different problems.

1. How to manipulate cameras (varies with camera type, regardless of GL version),
2. How to apply cameras (varies with GL version, regardless of camera type).

To complete my answer, once you updated your camera (cam.update) insted of calling `camera.apply(Gdx.gl10);` you give the matrix to your shader - it will depend on your shader, but the simplest case would be something like this:

```
shader.setUniformMatrix("u_modelviewporj_mat", cam.combined);
```

Comment: How to use it in `render` method? In `resize` method I init it like below: float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
      camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, 2f * aspectRatio, 2f); Then I rotate, translate it etc. in render method. How can I apply it? It requires GL10 but I need GL20. It has no any effect

Comment: To apply it in OpenGL20, you have to update it - cam.update()-, and then pass it to the shader (just like the ortho cameras). The model view projection matrix would be cam.combined

Comment: If you don't know how to use an Ortho camera in GLES 2.0 either, may be you should edit your question and ask how to use cameras in GLES 2.0, because there are no differences between using an ortho or perspective camera in GLES 2.0.

Comment: There are many examples with libGdx cameras, but they are used in GLES 1.0 - 1.1. Thank you for your first comment! It's useful and perhaps answer on my question!

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad it helped, I edited my answer to clarify and differentiate both problems